# Taking Screenshot of hooked OpenGL application

Tags: c#, opengl, dll, hook

I've a little problem. I would like to take a Screenshot of Genymotion. Since this is not that easy and requires OpenGL Hooking i've a DLL which is injected via Easyhook.

Now the DLL hooks the Method wglSwapBuffers() to process the buffer, take the screenshot and then return the buffer back to genymotion. The problem is, that it crashes the App (Kernelbase.dll) and/or mscorlib as soon as it try to use any OpenGL methods.

Removing those and just printing a text when SwapBuffers_Hooked is called works well.

Here's the dll which is injected into the process

```
   public class Main : EasyHook.IEntryPoint
{



    GlMon.GlMonInterface Interface;
    Stack<String> Queue = new Stack<String>();
    public LocalHook CreateBufferHook = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    public Main(
        RemoteHooking.IContext InContext,
        String InChannelName)
    {


        // connect to host...
        Interface = RemoteHooking.IpcConnectClient<GlMon.GlMonInterface>(InChannelName);

        Interface.Ping();
    }

    public void Run(
        RemoteHooking.IContext InContext,
        String InChannelName)
    {
        // install hook...
        try
        {

            CreateBufferHook = LocalHook.Create(LocalHook.GetProcAddress("opengl32.dll", "wglSwapBuffers"), new DwglSwapBuffers(SwapBuffers_Hooked), this);

            CreateBufferHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
        }
        catch (Exception ExtInfo)
        {
            Interface.ReportException(ExtInfo);

            return;
        }

        Interface.IsInstalled(RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId());

        RemoteHooking.WakeUpProcess();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                // transmit newly monitored file accesses...
                if (this.bitmap != null)
                {

                    Interface.onSwapBuffer(RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId(), "bitmap received. size=" + bitmap.Size);
                    this.bitmap = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Interface.onSwapBuffer(RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId(), "ping..");

                    Interface.Ping();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Ping() will raise an exception if host is unreachable
        }
        // wait for host process termination...

    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    delegate IntPtr DwglSwapBuffers(IntPtr hdc);



    [DllImport("opengl32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern IntPtr wglSwapBuffers(IntPtr hdc);


    // this is where we are intercepting all file accesses!
    static IntPtr SwapBuffers_Hooked(IntPtr hdc)
    {

        Main This = (Main)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback;

        try
        {

            /** apitrace dump is 
             *                                      
                11288 wglSwapBuffers(hdc = 0xb0013e0a) = TRUE
                11289 glFlush()
                11290 wglMakeCurrent(hdc = 0xf601374b, hglrc = 0x10004) = TRUE
                11291 glDisable(cap = GL_SCISSOR_TEST)
                11292 glClear(mask = GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
                11293 glEnable(cap = GL_SCISSOR_TEST)
                11294 glDisable(cap = GL_BLEND)
                11295 glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 20)
                11296 glPushClientAttrib(mask = GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT)
                11297 glPushAttrib(mask = GL_TRANSFORM_BIT)
                11298 glMatrixMode(mode = GL_PROJECTION)
                11299 glPushMatrix()
                11300 glLoadIdentity()
                11301 glGetIntegerv(pname = GL_VIEWPORT, params = {0, 0, 860, 720})
                11302 glOrtho(left = 0, right = 860, bottom = 0, top = 720, zNear = 0, zFar = -1)
                11303 glMatrixMode(mode = GL_TEXTURE)
                11304 glPushMatrix()
                11305 glLoadIdentity()
                11306 glMatrixMode(mode = GL_MODELVIEW)
                11307 glPushMatrix()                                     * **/
              Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(860, 720);
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 860, 720);
            BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            wgl.glReadBuffer((uint)wgl.DrawBufferMode.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);
            wgl.glReadPixels(0, 0, bounds.Width, bounds.Height, (uint)wgl.PixelFormat.GL_RGB, (uint)wgl.DataType.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bmpData.Scan0);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

            int i = 0;
            while (File.Exists("images/test_" + i + ".png"))
            {
                i++;
            }
            bitmap.Save("images/test_" + i + ".png");
        return wgl.SwapBuffers(hdc);


        }
        catch
        {
        }
        // call original API...
        return wglSwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
```

Error of the Crash is

```
Problemereignisname:    APPCRASH
Anwendungsname: player.exe
Anwendungsversion:  0.0.0.0
Anwendungszeitstempel:  54edc8da
Fehlermodulname:    KERNELBASE.dll
Fehlermodulversion: 6.3.9600.17415
```

Another Exception displayed by the debugger is a System.FileNotFoundexception but i cant figure out which file is not found.

Update: i have updated the code. This code works in most cases and the images are stored. Anyway, they have annoying colors. It looks like that some colors are missing and/or to less red color. What may caused this issue? if i choose another PixelFormat it crashes again. Same with GL_RGB. RGBA seems to crash. If i increase the DataType it crashes aswell. Any idea why the colors are cirpled?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet

```
IntPtr hglrc = wgl.GetCurrentDC();
[...]
wgl.MakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc);
```

is certainly not going to work (and might be the reason for the crash). `wglGetCurrentDC()` returns a *device context*, not the handle of the *GL context*. You could query the GL context by `glGetCurrentContext()`. Howerver, as the only operation you need seem to need the GL context handle for seems to be setting the current context, this would not help you at all. Either, the application leaves the context bound, then your operation is not neccessary at all, or, it unbinds it or uses several different contexts - then, you have to hook into `wglMakeCurrent` and actually track which context is going to render to what DC, so you can find out which context it is you need grab the buffer data from at the particual SwapBuffers call.

Your code has another issue: YOu are swapping the buffer twice: once, before you read the data, and once after. After a buffer swao, the contents of the back buffer become undefined. So there are two strategies you can follow:

1. grab the content of the back buffer, and then swap, OR
2. swap, and grab the content of the front buffer

but never swap twice.

Comment: thank you. I fogot to update the code. I got it working so far, but the colors are still corrupted. Any idea why?

Comment: Bitmaps use BGR format, not RGB. also make sure that all alignment rules are fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of the GRB problem is that the data of Genymotion is Big-endian and your hookprogram is Little-endian. Your should reverse the bytes array.

Comment: This may be the right answer, but as it stands, it looks more like a comment. You should add more details. Short answers like this one tend to get down-voted and/or deleted.